# Abrir imagem em div depois de carregar com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse código **jquery** que faz um filtro, quando mostra o resultado, abre em uma div **id=produtos**, nessa div irá ter thumbnails e **quero que clica na imagem e aparece em uma div ampliada do lado.**

O filtro está funcionando, o que não funciona é o **loader** para carregar imagem do lado.

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema para funcionar o jquery para aparecer a imagem em uma div depois que aparece o resultado do filtro?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.loader').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content_simulador').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
$('#categoria').on('change',function(){
        var categoriaID = $(this).val();
        if(categoriaID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'admin/ajaxData_simulador2.php',
                data:'categoria_id='+categoriaID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#subcategoria').html(html);
                    $('#produtos').html('<div class="container"><div class="col-md-12 filtro_simulador"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Selecione uma subcategoria</div></div>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#subcategoria').html('<option value="">Selecione uma categoria</option>');
            $('#produtos').html('<div class="col-md-12">Selecione um produto</div>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#subcategoria').on('change',function(){
        var produtosID = $(this).val();
        if(produtosID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'admin/ajaxData_simulador2.php',
                data:'produtos_id='+produtosID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#produtos').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#produtos').html('<div class="col-md-12">Selecione um produto</div>'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: o php está retornando correto a miniatura?

Comment: Sim está. O peoblema esta no jquery que quando gera o resultado do filtro na div, nao funciona o loader ali do jquery para aparecer a imagem do lado